# node.js connect to node from another webserver

Tags: node.js, cross-domain

Hey I have a website that running node.js on (for example)  80.80.80.80:3000

I want to get access to my node from another webserver, http://example.com/

when I add

```
script(src='http://80.80.80.80:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js)
script
    var socket = io.connect();
```

I got an error says "Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the socket.io script was not found under URL `http://80.80.80.80:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`. Check this URL from your browser if a javascript file is returned from the URL.

You can find a couple of examples how to use socket.io with connect, express or plain http node.js server on the [socket.io page](http://socket.io/#how-to-use).

Comment: in browser it's return js body